# Facebook Comment page through API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I've searched for a while but I've only found the Facebook UI, that has some basic dialogs. Maybe some of you know some iOS apps that can open the comments page in a new "page" (e.g. Flipboard). Is there a way to show the comment page directly from Facebook or I have to simulate it through the API?

UPDATE: Not a page comment box. I want to show the comments of a post.

Comment: Your answer lies here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/. See the `comments` connection of the `post` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to create a facebook app showing your comment box. The same comment box can be showed in different pages/ urls using the "data-href" url.

```
    <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></div>
```

You could eventually add an static url in a database or something like that to wich you can always refer.

I dont exactly know what you want but i hope this helps

Comment: no, not a page comment box. Let's say I get the latest posts and if the user clicks on "See comments" to redirect him to some mobile page that has the post's comments.